# Error in admin category tab?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, mysql, wordpress

I have updated with magento version 1.7 to 1.9. I get an error when click on edit category tab "Associated blog post" or "Associated blog category". i get the following error. My store is connected with wordpress.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT command
>   denied to user 'alisonan_wp'@'localhost' for table
>   'wordpress_association', query was: SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM
>   `wp_posts` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN
>   `alisonan_magento_dev`.`wordpress_association` AS `assoc` ON
>   `assoc`.`wordpress_object_id` = `main_table`.`ID` AND
>   `assoc`.`object_id` = 401 AND `assoc`.`type_id` = 3 AND
>   `assoc`.`store_id` IN ('1', 0) WHERE (`main_table`.`post_type`='post')
>   AND (`main_table`.`post_status` ='publish') AND (main_table.ID IN(0))

Comment: Your `mysql` user **alisonan_wp** don't have access to the wordpress database.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is purely a mysql based issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the user **alisonan_wp** doesn't have SELECT privilege granted for the **wordpress_association** table. You can fix this by granting the access to this user to this table, it maybe possible that you will have to grant access to other tables as well, not only to **wordpress_association**.

To do so try this:

```
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO 'alisonan_wp'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE ON mydb.wordpress_association TO 'alisonan_wp'@'localhost';
```

This is just an example and you should adjust it to your needs. Basically you are setting the set of privileges types a given user can have on a the whole DB (mydb.*) or for specific tables (mydb.wordpress_association).

For more detailed information check here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Answer (score 3):

The error simply says, the mysql user `alisonan_wp` does not have permission to access the table `wordpress_association` which is present inside the database `alisonan_magento_dev`.

If you give proper permission, the query will work. For this you can [***refer this thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767055/error-select-command-denied-to-user-useridip-address-for-table-table)